# table td width : as small as possible

Tags: html, css

My table is 100% width, how can I say in CSS: "the width of columns 2 and 3 should be as small as possible, without the content breaking."

I added style width, but it's not very recommended for the responsive. I didn't found any rule to do this.

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name : long width</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a very long row td</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a very long row td</td>
            <td>Ni</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>I would like to do a bit like this (but of course without specific width) :</p>


<table style="width: 100%;" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name : long width</th>
            <th style="width:40px">Value</th>
            <th style="width:40px">ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a very long row td</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a very long row td</td>
            <td>Ni</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width on table cells and it'll still expand to fit the content. Set the width to 0 and to stop it breaking can use the white-space:nowrap; css property. Just apply it to the columns you need using the nth-child() (and derivatives) selectors. It's also good to style your table in css rather than adding the style attribute to each cell, mainly when debugging problems. See the following example:

```css
table {
  width:100%;
}

table td:last-child, table td:nth-last-child(2)   {
  width:0px;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name : long width</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a very long row td</td>
            <td>Yes and No</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a very long row td</td>
            <td>Ni</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

More info here on [css selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) the [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) property

Answer (score 0):

```css
th {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%;" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name : long width</th>
            <th>Value</th>
            <th>ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a very long row td</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>This is a very long row td</td>
            <td>Ni</td>
            <td>13</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Seems working ! Thank you very much. I added a white-space:nowrap; to prevent breaking word with a hyphen.